# In a webservice Session timeout changing value is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Session timeout in webservice is not working getting an exception

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void resetsession()
{
  Session.Timeout = 1000;
}
```

```
Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/resetsession'.
```

Can any one look into the issue?

Comment: i updated can you please check my issue please provide soluton

Comment: `giving an error` isn't very descriptive. What does it say?

Comment: i have given an error, provide soution to issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what .NET version you're using, but I remember having this issue a long time ago, so maybe your [HTTP GET and HTTP POST is disabled](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;819267)?

Then the solution would be to add this to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And maybe you also need this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Found [this article](http://www.violato.net/blog/net/97-request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-unexpectedly-ending-in-mymethodname) with a little bit more information.